# Javascript nested array average price

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the nested array,
I want to access products[] array.

I can access console.log(shoppingcart[0].products[0]); // {productId: 1111, quantity: 3, price: 3}

but I do not know how to get the average value of the price in the nested product[] array.

```
1) products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 3, price: 3.0 }
        ]


2) products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 1, price: 3.0 },
          { productId: 1112, quantity: 1, price: 1.0 }
        ]
```

**output should be**
price: 3.0
price: 3.0
price: 1.0
and

3 + 3 + 1 = 7 / 3
average: 2.33

This is my code below.

```
let shoppingcart = [
      {
        orderId: 100000,
        dayofWeeks:  "May.06.2020",
        products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 3, price: 3.0 }
        ]
      },
      
      {
        orderId: 100001,
        dayofWeeks: "Aug.12.2020",
        products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 1, price: 3.0 },
          { productId: 1112, quantity: 1, price: 1.0 }
        ]
      },
];
```

Comment: Get the sum of `shoppingcart[i].products[j].price` and divide by `shoppingcart[i].products.length`

Comment: is this possible to use nesting For Loops????

Comment: Yes, that's how you should do it.

Comment: It might help to do a little research, make an attempt, and then let us know what you tried and what specifically goes wrong. Using loops seems like a good start.

Comment: Thanks now I am trying, and I added output example, thanks a lot, :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is what you want here.

```
let shoppingCart = [
      {
        orderId: 100000,
        dayofWeeks:  "May.06.2020",
        products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 3, price: 3.0 }
        ]
      },
      
      {
        orderId: 100001,
        dayofWeeks: "Aug.12.2020",
        products: [
          { productId: 1111, quantity: 1, price: 3.0 },
          { productId: 1112, quantity: 1, price: 1.0 }
        ]
      },
];

const prices = shoppingCart.flatMap(c => c.products.map(p => p.price));

const average = prices.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / prices.length;
console.log(`average: ${average}`);
```